# How to styling xml using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

Anyone can help me to give an idea how to display this xml file as html table using xslt?
I am newbie with xslt.
Any advice really appreciated.

The total of `<Type>` in my xml is always different. The value of `<que>`,`<pro>`, and `<don>` as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="File.xsl"?> 
<report>
    <Type>AUTO</Type>
        <BID>601</BID>
        <que>3</que>
            <CRM>A1,A2,A3</CRM>
            <Country>ABA,ABE,ABD</Country>
            <Prefix>BNB</Prefix>
        <pro>1</pro>
            <CRM>W1</CRM>
            <Country>UUF/Country>
            <Prefix>BNB</Prefix>
        <don>2</don>
            <CRM>W2,W3</CRM>
            <Country>UUW,ABF</Country>
            <Prefix>BNB</Prefix>

    <Type>Direct</Type>
        <BID>602</BID>
        <que>3</que>
            <CRM>A1,A2,A3</CRM>
            <Country>ABA,ABE,ABD</Country>
            <Prefix>BNB</Prefix>
        <pro>1</pro>
            <CRM>W1</CRM>
            <Country>UUF/Country>
            <Prefix>BNB</Prefix>
        <don>2</don>
            <CRM>W2,W3</CRM>
            <Country>UUW,ABF</Country>
            <Prefix>BNB</Prefix>
</report>
```

My expectation table is like this:
[image]

Comment: add <xsl:output method="html" /> after <xsl:stylesheet

Comment: If you want to use XSLT to transform your XML to a certain HTML table layout and style then the question is more about HTML and CSS than XSLT as the particular HTML layout and CSS style can simply be used in the XSLT in the templates you write. So if you have the HTML and CSS for the particular table you have shown then include it. If you need help with that then use the tags for HTML and CSS after reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Styling_tables and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: You have indented your XML, which usually suggests nested elements. Yet, the `Type`, `BID`, `que`, etc, elements are actually all direct children of the `report` element. This does make the XML slightly harder to process. Do you have any control over the structure of the XML? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC I dont have it :

Comment: Your "expectation table" does not fit your input.